# How to debug in Tensorflow2?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am new to Tensorflow and am currently working on Tensorflow2. I'm still having a hard time writing code, because I don't have the possibility to debug.

I already tried to get further with the line:

```
tf.executing_eagerly()

and

tf.print()
```

but this is only a small help compared to the "normal" debugging in python.

Is there a better possibility to debug the code and to view the content of variables?

The only thing I currently get is this view, but that doesn't give me any insight into the actual variables either:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `tf.print`, use the normal Python's `print` if you are eagerly executing. You will be able to see the contents of the variables.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see the content of the variable. I see information during debugging like "dtype", "shape", "graph", "value_index" and "_name" but unfortunately no information about the content of the tensor

Comment: If you are eagerly executing, it will show you the contents.

Comment: if I use print() in eager mode i get the following output: array([<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_6:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>,
       <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_8:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>,
       <tf.Tensor 'add_4:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>,
       <tf.Tensor 'add_5:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>], dtype=object)

Comment: Just type the variable name and hit enter. If you are doing this in terminal or else just leave the name of variable there and run the code.

Comment: I use Visual Studio code as IDE. If I enter the pure variable name in a line, then no output is generated or nothing is output on the console

Comment: I added a picture of my currenct debugging view